# Google Cloud Talent API - Java: Library Missing or example outdated?

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-talent-solution

After importing 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-talent:0.36.1' (from here: https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) into my build.gradle file and running, the class 'TenantOrProjectName' from the documentation cannot resolve to a type in Eclipse.

When looking through the api documentation, I didn't see a class with that name in it either. I'm wondering if either the example is outdated or if I'm missing a library that isn't in the Java documentation.

Steps to duplicate(in Java)
1.)Copy 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-talent:0.36.1' into build.gradle file, then run:
gradle cleanEclipse
gradle cleanEclipsewtp
gradle eclipse
gradle eclipsewtp

on command line.

2.) Copy and paste searchJobs() method from here:

(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/talent-v4beta1-samples/jobs/v4/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/talent/v4beta1/JobSearchHistogramSearch.java)

into Java program and 'TenantOrProjectName' can't be imported as it isn't recognized by Spring.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing a library because that's kind of what it feels like at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documentation is out to date. I recommend you to take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/java-talent/issues/132) for further references. [In here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-talent/releases/tag/v0.36.0) you can find the breaking changes for the v0.36.0 and it is recomended to use TenantName for resources in place of TenantOrProjectName.